# Windows 10 VPN powershell

Tags: powershell

I have

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name "TESTVPN" -ServerAddress "company.vpn.com" -TunnelType L2tp -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2 -EncryptionLevel Required -L2tpPsk "password" -RememberCredential -Force
```

So right now, I have the Microsoft CHAP Verson 2, but how can I also enable PAP using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you did for Chap. Just change the Auth type.

```
$addVpnConnectionParams = @{
    AuthenticationMethod = 'Pap'
    Name = "TESTVPN"
    TunnelType = 'L2tp'
    EncryptionLevel = 'Required'
    Force = $true
    RememberCredential = $true
    ServerAddress = "company.vpn.com"
    L2tpPsk = "password"
}
Add-VpnConnection @addVpnConnectionParams
```

Are saying you tried that and it did not work for you?

***Update for the OP***

As for …

> Yes, but I need PAP and Microsoft CHAP Verson 2

I just looked at your original sample, and noticed that you have …

```
-EncryptionLevel Required
```

... which expect by default EAP or MS-CHAPv2, not PAP.

The...

```
Add-VpnConnection
```

... cmdlet has been reported to have issues with that setting and tryin to use PAP. You end up seeing errors like...

> "The current encryption selection requires EAP or MS-CHAPv2 logon
>   security methods. PAP and CHAP do not support Encryption settings
>   'Required' or 'Maximum". : The parameter is incorrect.

You can try using the cmdlet using only MS-CHAPv2 then try editing the file created, normally located here:

> C:\Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk

It's rally noting more than an .ini text file, and I've never tried to modify it, but again, it's just a text file.

Or using the Set-VpnConnection after the Add-vpnConnection to modify the Auth settings.

The property is an array...

```
[[-AuthenticationMethod] <String[]>]
```

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/set-vpnconnection?view=win10-ps

```
Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection
...
AuthenticationMethod  : {Chap, MsChapv2, Pap}
EncryptionLevel       : Optional
...
```

... So, just enter both as an array.

Comment: Yes, but I need PAP and Microsoft CHAP Verson 2

Answer (score 0):

To enable PAP just add a comma to separate MSChapv2.

```bsh
Add-VpnConnection -Name "Test3" 
  -ServerAddress "yourserveraddress.com" 
  -TunnelType "L2tp" -EncryptionLevel "Required" 
  -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2,PAP -UseWinlogonCredential -SplitTunneling 
  -RememberCredential -PassThru
```